# How Create Decade Field Calculated

Tags: calculated-column

Hello I'm having trouble creating a calculated field
I managed to create a field that takes the date of an event

```
=YEAR([Event Date])
```

however I needed to create another calculated field, this needs to catch the decade of the year, but I have no idea how to do it.

is there any formula to create this type of field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could use FLOOR for this:

```
=FLOOR(YEAR([Event Date]),10)
```